# how to apply regex on iteration in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one issue while iterating the regex.

```
def wordsaraemovalFromPpt():
        pptxListremove = []
        for i in pptxFileList:
            ppt = Presentation(i)
            for j in userInputForRemove: #["Car","car","caR","Cars","ZZCarSzz"]
                for slide in ppt.slides:
                    for shape in slide.shapes:
                        if shape.has_text_frame:
                            pattern = re.findall(j, shape.text, re.IGNORECASE)
                            pptxListremove.extend(pattern)
                print(pptxListremove)
            ppt.save(i)
    wordsaraemovalFromPpt()
```

Suppose in ppt file i have word like "Car","car","caR","Cars","ZZCarSzz".

but i want only "Car","car","caR",

i dont want "Cars","ZZCarSzz"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a list comprehension for this:

```
pptxListremove = [x for x in userInputForRemove if x.lower() == "car"]
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need regex for that. Just use the `filter` built-in function

```
your_list = ["Car","car","caR","Cars","ZZCarSzz"]
your_list = list(filter(lambda w: w.lower() == "car", your_list))
print(your_list)
```

and output

```
['Car', 'car', 'caR']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_list = ["Car","car","caR","Cars","ZZCarSzz"]
your_list = list(filter(lambda w: w.lower() == "car", your_list))
print(your_list)
```

It worked for me. Thanks